# debian: aptitude install sshfs > Couldn't find any package whose name

Tags: debian, aptitude, sshfs

Why aptitude don’t found sshfs?
And how can I install sshfs via aptitude? Pleas, without 3rd-Partys.

https://packages.debian.org/en/wheezy/sshfs

I typed this:

```
root@s18:~# aptitude update
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Sources
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy Release
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/non-free Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/main Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/contrib Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/non-free Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/non-free amd64 Packages
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en

root@s18:~# aptitude dist-upgrade
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

root@s18:~# aptitude install sshfs
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "sshfs"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "sshfs"
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

root@s18:~# cat /etc/debian_version 
7.5
root@s18:~#
```

My sources:

```
root@s18:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
root@s18:~# ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
root@s18:~#
```

And

```
root@s18:~# aptitude search sshfs
root@s18:~# apt-cache search sshfs       
root@s18:~# apt-get -s install sshfs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sshfs
root@s18:~#
```

Comment: `aptitude search sshfs` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `apt-cache search sshfs` and `apt-get -s install sshfs`.

Comment: I add the output of that.

Comment: `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy contrib non-free` try ading `main` here.

Comment: I forget the `main`. After adding it and update, `aptitude install sshfs` works fine.

Comment: I cannot answere my own questions, but your fix work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your primary `deb` source line:

> `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy contrib non-free`

This pulls in the `contrib` and `non-free` respositories of the `wheezy` version, *but not the `main` repository* which is where most of Debian lives. You are however pulling in security updates for *main* as well; I suppose sshfs just hasn't had anything that warrants a release there since Wheezy was released.

As was found out in comments to the question, adding the `main` repository solves the problem:

> `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free`